# Magento Export CSV: repeated columns?

Tags: csv, export, dataflow, column, stock-status

I have a csv produced with DataFlow->export all products. Some columns seem to be repeated. Does anyone know the difference between the following sets of column names, all of which are found in the default "Export all Products"?

```
First                       Second
stock_status_changed_auto   stock_status_changed_automatically
use_config_enable_qty_inc   use_config_enable_qty_increments
```

Comment: Are the values for the columns identical for individual products?

Comment: @tsHunter, yes the columns with similar names have identical values

Comment: Magento doesn't always do a great job of cleaning up code. If the values are always the same, I would assume it is just a case of them failing to delete some duplicates in the code.